# Can an unhosted website be redirected to a specific page?

Tags: redirect

I have two websites hosted on the same server... [www.1.com](http://www.1.com) and [www.2.com](http://www.2.com) and the pages within them are virtually identical. I want to have [www.2.com](http://www.2.com) shut down, and removed from the server. Once I do this then page links on the Internet will become broken. However, I want to keep the [www.2.com](http://www.2.com) domain name and redirect it to [www.1.com](http://www.1.com).

Here's my question. If someone were to click a link that said [www.2.com/example](http://www.2.com/example), would it redirect to [www.1.com/example](http://www.1.com/example), or would the link still remain broken? In other words, is my redirect only for the homepage, or will all other pages work as well?

Answer (score 0):

Okay... looks like I answered my own question. I redirected my 2nd site to the 1st one, and waited over night. This morning I typed in my 2nd site within the address bars of multiple browsers and they all forwarded to the homepage of the 1st site. So, then I typed my 2nd site again, but added a page extension. It forwarded to that very same page on my 1st site, so all is well. Links on the Internet with the 2nd site name, and allocated page, should not be broken now. They forward to the page in question on my 1st site.